# How to add a row with data driven drop down to DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

I am trying dynamically add a row to a datatables.net table where the third column is a drop down select.

I been trying various different google searches and have it working for the most part when I use a local variable of "times", but I am not sure how to access the "new_location" data array within the row's data source and populate the drop down options from the "new_location"

The new_location array is an array of objects containing two options of location_id and location_name.  I want the drop down to use the location_id as the selected value and display the location_name.

You can test it using any of the following serial numbers:
0111398-0212RV-001
0111398-0212RV-002
0111244-2030RV-001
0111244-2030RV-002
0111244-2030RV-003

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>DataTables - Child rows</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.css">
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.5/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>




  <style type="text/css">
  .select-item {
   padding: 0 0 0 100px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <!-- TODO: Missing CoffeeScript 2 -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
  
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function search(nameKey, myArray){
    for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].serial_num === nameKey) {
            return myArray[i];
        }
    }
}


$(document).ready(function() {

var times = [
 "12:00 am", 
 "1:00 am", 
 "2:00 am", 
 "3:00 am", 
 "4:00 am", 
 "5:00 am", 
 "6:00 am", 
 "7:00 am", 
 "8:00 am", 
 "9:00 am", 
 "10:00 am", 
 "11:00 am", 
 "12:00 pm", 
 "1:00 pm", 
 "2:00 pm", 
 "3:00 pm", 
 "4:00 pm", 
 "5:00 pm", 
 "6:00 pm", 
 "7:00 pm", 
 "8:00 pm", 
 "9:00 pm", 
 "10:00 pm", 
 "11:00 pm"
];

 
    var table2 = $('#example2').DataTable( {
        "columns": [
            { "data": "serial_num" },
            { "data": "location" },
          {
              "render": function(d,t,r){
                  var $select = $("<select></select>", {
                      "id": r[0]+"start",
                         "value": d
                   });
                  
                  $.each(times, function(k,v){
                      var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                          "text": v,
                             "value": v
                         });
                         if(d === v){
                          $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                         }
                      $select.append($option);
                   });
                   return $select.prop("outerHTML");
               }
           }
       ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );


  $( function() {
     $( "#next1" ).click(function() {
        var data_details = [{serial_num:"0111244-2030RV-001",location:"Shipped",new_locations:[{"location_id":5,"location_name":"PSQ1"},{"location_id":6,"location_name":"PSQ2"},{"location_id":21,"location_name":"RGA"}]},{serial_num:"0111244-2030RV-002",location:"Finished Goods",new_locations:[{"location_id":5,"location_name":"PSQ1"},{"location_id":6,"location_name":"PSQ2"},{"location_id":21,"location_name":"Retain Cage"}]},{serial_num:"0111244-2030RV-003",location:"Finished Goods",new_locations:[{"location_id":5,"location_name":"PSQ1"},{"location_id":6,"location_name":"PSQ2"},{"location_id":21,"location_name":"Retain Cage"}]},{serial_num:"0111398-0212RV-001",location:"Post Sterilization Quarantine2",new_locations:[{"location_id":5,"location_name":"PSQ1"},{"location_id":6,"location_name":"PSQ2"}]},{serial_num:"0111398-0212RV-002",location:"Post Sterilization Quarantine2",new_locations:[{"location_id":5,"location_name":"PSQ1"},{"location_id":6,"location_name":"PSQ2"}]}];
        var x = search($("#serial").val(),data_details);
        table2.row.add(x).draw();
        
       });
       

  });

});


</script>

</head>
<body>
   <table id="example2" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>ID</th>
             <th>Serial/Lot Number</th>
             <th>Status</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tfoot>
         <tr>
             <th>ID</th>
             <th>Serial/Lot Number</th>
             <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
     </tfoot>
  </table>
  <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" value="0111398-0212RV-001" id="serial"><button id="next1">Search For Serial</button>
```

Thanks
Jlimited

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out.

Updated code below.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>DataTables - Child rows</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.css">
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.5/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>




  <style type="text/css">
  .select-item {
   padding: 0 0 0 100px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <!-- TODO: Missing CoffeeScript 2 -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
  
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function search(nameKey, myArray){
    for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].serial_num === nameKey) {
            return myArray[i];
        }
    }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
 
    var table2 = $('#example2').DataTable( {
        "columns": [
            { "data": "serial_num" },
            { "data": "location" },
          { "data": "new_locations", "autoWidth":true,
              "render": function(d,t,r){
                  var $select = $("<select></select>", {
                      "id": r[0]+"start",
                         "value": d
                   });
                  
                  $.each(d, function(k,v){
                      var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                          "text": v.location_name,
                             "value": v.location_id
                         });
                         if(d === v){
                          $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                         }
                      $select.append($option);
                   });
                   return $select.prop("outerHTML");
               }
           }
       ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );


  $( function() {
     $( "#next1" ).click(function() {
        var data_details = [{serial_num:"0111244-2030RV-001",location:"Shipped",new_locations:[{"location_id":5,"location_name":"PSQ1"},{"location_id":6,"location_name":"PSQ2"},{"location_id":21,"location_name":"RGA"}]},{serial_num:"0111244-2030RV-002",location:"Finished Goods",new_locations:[{"location_id":5,"location_name":"PSQ1"},{"location_id":6,"location_name":"PSQ2"},{"location_id":21,"location_name":"Retain Cage"}]},{serial_num:"0111244-2030RV-003",location:"Finished Goods",new_locations:[{"location_id":5,"location_name":"PSQ1"},{"location_id":6,"location_name":"PSQ2"},{"location_id":21,"location_name":"Retain Cage"}]},{serial_num:"0111398-0212RV-001",location:"Post Sterilization Quarantine2",new_locations:[{"location_id":5,"location_name":"PSQ1"},{"location_id":6,"location_name":"PSQ2"}]},{serial_num:"0111398-0212RV-002",location:"Post Sterilization Quarantine2",new_locations:[{"location_id":5,"location_name":"PSQ1"},{"location_id":6,"location_name":"PSQ2"}]}];
        var x = search($("#serial").val(),data_details);
        table2.row.add(x).draw();
        
       });
       

  });

});


</script>

</head>
<body>
   <table id="example2" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>ID</th>
             <th>Serial/Lot Number</th>
             <th>Status</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tfoot>
         <tr>
             <th>ID</th>
             <th>Serial/Lot Number</th>
             <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
     </tfoot>
  </table>
  <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" value="0111398-0212RV-001" id="serial"><button id="next1">Search For Serial</button>
```